# Replace string by integer in sublists (all ocurrences) - python

Tags: python

This an example of a possible list with the sublists:

```
  rows = [[1, 1, 'x'], [1, 'x', 1], [1, 1, 'x'], [1, 'x', 1], ['x', 1, 1], ['x', 1, 1]]
```

I am looking for an efficient way to replace 'x' either by 0 or 1 in the sublists. 
The sublists has no fixed sized or number. I mean, it could be a list like this one:

```
    [(1, 1, 'x', 'x'), (1, 1, 'x', 'x'), (1, 'x', 1, 'x'), (1, 'x', 'x', 1)]
```

I tried this:

```
  for row in rows:
      for pos in row:
        if pos == 'x':
           pos.replace('x','0')
```

Even knowning that I need '0' as an integer, just to print an output. But rows kept the 'x' unchanged.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Strings are immutable, `replace` returns a new string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a `list` comprehension and check the value and replace that like,

```
>> rows = [[1, 1, 'x'], [1, 'x', 1], [1, 1, 'x'], [1, 'x', 1], ['x', 1, 1], ['x', 1, 1]]
>>> [[0 if y == 'x' else y  for y in x] for x in rows] # replace `x` with 0
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]

>>> another = [(1, 1, 'x', 'x'), (1, 1, 'x', 'x'), (1, 'x', 1, 'x'), (1, 'x', 'x', 1)]
>>> [[5 if y == 'x' else y  for y in x] for x in another] # replace `x` with 5
[[1, 1, 5, 5], [1, 1, 5, 5], [1, 5, 1, 5], [1, 5, 5, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
rows = [[1, 1, 'x'], [1, 'x', 1], [1, 1, 'x'], [1, 'x', 1], ['x', 1, 1], ['x', 1, 1]]

temp_dic = {'x':0}
modified_list  = map(
  lambda sub_list: sub_list if 'x' not in sub_list else [temp_dic.get(n, n) for n in sub_list],
  rows)
print(list(modified_list))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Basically, we are iterating through the sublist and checking if a value (0) is present for the key (x). If yes, replace it, otherwise, keep the key.

`dic.get(n, n)` returns the value(0) if it exists or it simply just returns key (e.g numbers in our case). This way we only replace the 'x' not the numbers.

Comment: When I run the code I got this: NameError: name 'dic' is not defined

Comment: Fixed it! It was a variable name typo. try now

Answer (score 1):

```
rows = [[1, 1, 'x'], [1, 'x', 1], [1, 1, 'x'], [1, 'x', 1], ['x', 1, 1], ['x', 1, 1]]

for r in rows:
    for i, pos in enumerate(r):
        if pos == 'x':
            r[i] = 0
print(rows)

#output replace x with 0: [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
#output replace x with 99: [[1, 1, 99], [1, 99, 1], [1, 1, 99], [1, 99, 1], [99, 1, 1], [99, 1, 1]]
```

This works well for me on Python 3.7.4. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you still wanted to use the replace method, you would need to append the values to a new list after replacing the string:

```
rows=[(1, 1, 'x', 'x'), (1, 1, 'x', 'x'), (1, 'x', 1, 'x'), (1, 'x', 'x', 1)]

new_list=[]
for row in rows:
    sublist=[]
    for pos in row:
        if pos == 'x':
            pos=pos.replace('x','0')
        sublist.append(pos)
    new_list.append(sublist)

print(new_list)
# [[1, 1, '0', '0'], [1, 1, '0', '0'], [1, '0', 1, '0'], [1, '0', '0', 1]]
```

Comment: As I said, I need to keep the '0's or '1's as integers. Your solution is not good for me in this particular case. Thanks, anyway.